# Add Computed Column with Liquibase

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

How can I add a computed column in liquibase? When I run the following SQL in a sql tag I get the computed value I'm expecting:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD ComputedColumn AS (CASE WHEN DateColumn1 IS NULL OR DateColumn2 IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, DateColumn1, DateColumn2) END)
```

How do I do this without using an sql tag? I am able to get a column created with the following yaml:

`- addColumn:
      tableName: TableName
      columns:
        - column:
            name: ComputedColumn
            type: tinyint
            constraints:
              nullable: true
            defaultValueComputed:  0
            valueComputed:  DATEDIFF(DAY, DateColumn1, DateColumn2) END`

However the column type is not Computed like when I run the raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Had no luck using the suggested solution.
But here is my working one:

```
- addColumn:
  tableName: TableName
  columns:
    - column:
        name: ComputedColumn as (case when ((([fieldFlagOne]+(0))+([fieldFlagTwo]+(0)))+([fieldFlagThree]+(0)))=(3) then (1) else (0) end)
        computed: true
        type: ""
        constraints:
          nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the computed column expression for the type, like this - note that the expression is also a YAML folded style, which I have found prevents Liquibase from mangling the expression:

```
- addColumn:
  tableName: TableName
  columns:
    - column:
        name: ComputedColumn
        type: > 
            tinyint AS (DATEDIFF(DAY, DateTimestamp, DateTimestamp))
        constraints:
          nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to fixup helpful @Philipp's answer with [`modifySql`](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/modify-sql.html) as Liquibase 3.x kept generating empty type placeholder `[]` for SQL Server like in

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD ComputedColumn as (case when ((([fieldFlagOne]+(0))+([fieldFlagTwo]+(0)))+([fieldFlagThree]+(0)))=(3) then (1) else (0) end) []`

that led to `[S1000][1038] An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.` error:

```
- addColumn:
  tableName: TableName
  columns:
    - column:
        name: ComputedColumn as (case when ((([fieldFlagOne]+(0))+([fieldFlagTwo]+(0)))+([fieldFlagThree]+(0)))=(3) then (1) else (0) end)
        computed: true
        type: ""
        constraints:
          nullable: true
- modifySql:
    replace:
      replace: "[]"
      with: ""
```